# MySQL query results are not a resource

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am having trouble with the query in this code.  The problem is one I have had before, the `$num = mysql_num_rows($result);` part gives me a MySQL error saying it expected a resource.  Usually when I have this error it is because I misplaced a single quote some where, but after looking I cannot find any problem, though this query is a bit more complex than what I usually have to deal with.

```
//connect to the database and stuff

$last_year = idate("Y")-1;
$month = date("m");
$day = date("d");                                   

$query = "SELECT bills.b_id, bills.c_id, bills.grand_total, bills.void, bills.date_added,
                 customers.b_name, customers.l_name, customers.f_name, customers.phone 
          FROM bills, customers 
          WHERE bills.c_id = customers.c_id 
                AND bills.void = '0' 
                AND date_added BETWEEN '".$last_year."-".$month."-".$day."' AND CURDATE()";
$result = mysql_query($query);
mysql_close($link);                 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

**EDIT:**

Although I already know the `mysql_close()` function is not the problem I went ahead and removed it and my code still does not work.  This **EXACT** same code (other than the query) works in nearly a dozen other pages.  **The problem is in the query**, the MySQL error (as stated before) is `mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource`.  I am working on getting the specific error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some error handling to your code.

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if ( !$result ) {
  echo 'the query failed: ', mysql_error();
  die;
}
```

(in "real" production code you might not want to display the actual query and error message to just any arbitrary user though).

see also: http://docs.php.net/mysql_error

Comment: I already said the error was `mysql_num_row()` expected a resource.

Comment: `mysql_error` is not the same as a PHP error. The former will show issues with the query, the latter issues with the script.

Comment: Thanks, just commented under @Col. Shrapnel's answer saying that I didn't understand that before :)

Comment: Found the problem, forgot to add `bills.` before `date_added`.

Comment: die is the worst way to handle errors. as well as echoing sensitive information directly to the browser

Answer (score 1):

1. Check to see if there were mysql errors. If you don't already have error reporting turned on, turn it on for development (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`).
2. Try waiting to close your mysql connection until after you're done with the result sets.

Comment: The link was closed only after $results had been populated.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the *mysql_close()* function at the end. If you close the mysql connection, *mysql_num_rows()* is not going to work

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
.
.
//Any others mysql operations
.
.
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: It works in the same code on nearly a dozen other pages with different (simpler) queries.

Answer (score 0):

You close link to mysql before retrieving query results. That's the problem. Just don't use mysql_close() as PHP can automatically handle it.

Comment: The link was closed only after `$results` had been populated.

Answer (score 0):

"not a resource" error means your query failed.
change your mysql_query call in that manner

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$query);
```

and see what's wrong with your query.
always do it this way to keep in touch with every error may occur

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't getting that you guys were asking me to look for a specific error, I though you were retards because I told you the error was that `mysql_num_rows() expected parameter 1 to be a resource` but I was the retard because you were basically telling me to dig deeper and find WHY it wasn't a resource.  Got it now :)